# Relation between (relative) Kullback-Liebler divergence and convergence of densities.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, entropy

Assume we have a reference measure $\mu$ and an absolutely continuous measure $P$ with Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{dP}{d\mu}=p$.

Assume furthermore that we have a sequence of probability measures $Q_n, n=1,2,...$ with Radon-Nikodym derivatives  $\frac{dQ_n}{d\mu}=q_n$.

I would like to know if it's possible to establish a "hierarchy" (which one is "stronger") between the following statements:

1. $$\mathbb L^1(\Omega)-\lim_{n\to\infty} q_n=p$$
2. $$D_{KL}(Q_n\|P)\to 0, \; as\; n\to\infty$$

where $D_{KL}$ denotes the Kullback-Liebler divergence.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit unfamiliar with your notation -- does the first statement refer to  convergence  of $q_n$ to $p$ in total variation distance? If so, then statement 2 is stronger than statement 1, which follows from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinsker%27s_inequality .

Comment: @Artemy the first statement just means that the sequence $(q_n)$ converges in $L^1$-norm to $p$.

Comment: For probability densities  $L^1$-norm is the same as total variation distance. Hence, Pinsker's inequality implies that if $D_{KL}(q_n\Vert p)\to 0$, then $\Vert q_n - p \Vert_1 \to 0$. The result is actually more general: for any sequences of measures $\{Q_n\}_n$ and $\{P_n\}_n$ (which may or may not be expressible as densities), $D_{KL}(Q_n\Vert P_n)\to 0$ implies convergence in total variation.